# JS Classes - cannot understand this method syntax

Tags: javascript

So i get struggle with this:

```
class MyClass {

    // ...

    [Symbol.iterator]() {} // method with computed name (symbol here)
}
```

What does it mean method with computed name?

Comment: Exactly that - it's a method whose property key is computed, in this case as a symbol.

Comment: Have you seen computed property keys in object literals before?